# How can call a function only after the completion of another

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

How to call a function  after the completion of another  task .
I am trying to update an inputbox value, after the completion of each(function ().

I have an html table with more than one rows. It has the column 'HolidayEnt'  is updated with the value coming from controller function 'GetSystemCalculatedHolidayByDate' in each row . After that update in 'HolidayEnt' column in each row  of the table [After updating all the rows] ,  I have to update the value from netMinutes variable into inputbox totmins control outside of the table. But the 'totmins' column is updated with 0 first time even after the completion of each loop

Here is the code

```js
var netMinutes = 0.00;
$("#btnCalculate").click(function () {
var netMinutes = 0.00;
var eachMinutes = 0.00;

$('#tblEntry tbody tr').each(function () {
var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var sunHrs = tr.find("#SundayNetHrs").val();
var monHrs = tr.find("#MondayNetHrs").val();
var tueHrs = tr.find("#TuesdayNetHrs").val();
var wedHrs = tr.find("#WednesdayNetHrs").val();
var thuHrs = tr.find("#ThursdayNetHrs").val();
var friHrs = tr.find("#FridayNetHrs").val();
var satHrs = tr.find("#SaturdayNetHrs").val();
var netHrs = tr.find("#NetHrsPerWeek").val();
var fromDate = tr.find("#FromDate").val();
var toDate = tr.find("#ToDate").val();


$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "/Employee/GetSystemCalculatedHolidayByDate?EID=" + $("#EmployeeID option:selected").val()
+ "&NetHrs=" + netHrs
+ "&Sunday=" + sunHrs
+ "&Monday=" + monHrs
+ "&Tuesday=" + tueHrs
+ "&Wednesday=" + wedHrs
+ "&Thursday=" + thuHrs
+ "&Friday=" + friHrs
+ "&Saturday=" + satHrs
+ "&Fromdate=" + fromDate
+ "&Todate=" + toDate,

contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
var systemHoliday = JSON.parse(data);
systemHoliday = systemHoliday.toFixed(2);
var time = systemHoliday.split('.');
eachMinutes = parseInt(time[0] * 60) + parseInt(time[1]);
netMinutes += eachMinutes
tr.find("#HolidayEnt").val(systemHoliday);


},
failure: function (response) {
console.log(response.responseText);
},
error: function (response) {
console.log(response.responseText);
}
});

});

$("#totmins").val(netMinutes);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="totmins"  asp-for="TotalEntMins" class="form-control " data-role="text"> 

<table id="tblEntry" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FromDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ToDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SundayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MondayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TuesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.WednesdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ThursdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FridayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SaturdayNetHrs, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NetHrsPerWeek, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100 empHrs" } })</td>
      <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HolidayEnt, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", @class = "form-control  w-100"  }  })</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Controller Method

```
public decimal GetSystemCalculatedHolidayByDate(int EID, string NetHrs, string Sunday, string Monday, string Tuesday, string Wednesday, 
            string Thursday, string Friday, string Saturday, string Fromdate, string Todate)
        {
                decimal SystemHoliday = 0.00M;
            
            if (EID > 0)
            {
                SystemHoliday = 210.30
            }
                return SystemHoliday;
        }
```

Comment: each is not an async funcation, so what  is stopping you from putting it inside the each() { ...  calculfunc(netMinutes) });

Comment: each is not async it is just shorthand for looping over the elements

Answer (score 0):

For optimizations and correct use of event loop, you should use async call using Promise or async/await.
Why do you want to run your code synchronously?

Comment: Is there anyway  to call the method calculfunc(netMinutes) after each loop complete.  Because the  calculfunc function argument netMinutes is getting after the completion of each loop

Answer (score 0):

try using loop. i cant figure out the result cz i dont have the html data. can you test this code? and let me know the result so we can fix it.

```js
var netMinutes = 0.00;
$("#btnCalculate").click(function () {
  let empEnt = 200;
  for( let elm_ of $('#tblEntry tbody tr') ){
      let 
      tr = elm_.closest('tr'),
      sunHrs = tr.find("#SundayNetHrs").val(),
      monHrs = tr.find("#MondayNetHrs").val(),
      tueHrs = tr.find("#TuesdayNetHrs").val(),
      wedHrs = tr.find("#WednesdayNetHrs").val(),
      thuHrs = tr.find("#ThursdayNetHrs").val(),
      friHrs = tr.find("#FridayNetHrs").val(),
      satHrs = tr.find("#SaturdayNetHrs").val(),
      netHrs = tr.find("#NetHrsPerWeek").val(),
      fromDate = tr.find("#FromDate").val(),
      toDate = tr.find("#ToDate").val();
  }
  calculfunc(netMinutes)
});
```

Comment: Still not working . Also after changing the code all hrs became undefined

Comment: can you post the html please?